# "2013-10-21 12:00:00.004" string convert to datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime

How to convert "2013-10-21 12:00:00.004" to datetime object in Python?
The problem is there is decimal number in seconds.

Comment: Why are the milliseconds a problem? It looks simple to parse. Can you show your code that parses the text.

Comment: a = datetime.strptime("2013-10-21 12:00:00.004", "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

Comment: And what happens when you do that?

Comment: @user5025141 Your bug is in the %y, you need %Y as in my answer below

Comment: Read this: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior Next time you ask a question make sure you include the full, but minimal, code necessary reproduce the problem, and the error message. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I will do that in the future.

Comment: sorry, I will do that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

here is a **working** example

```
import datetime

dt =  datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-10-21 12:00:00.004", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
print (dt.microsecond)
```

Comment: How did you answer this after the question was closed?

Comment: @David Heffernan It was still open when I started to write it I guess